# OAuth facebook login not working normally

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebooksdk.net

I use asp.net MVC webapi, and have been using facebook login for a long time. But suddenly there is an error as below:

[image: Not Logged In: You are not logged in. Please login and try again.]

bellow my code: **Startup.Auth.cs**

```
FacebookAuthenticationOptions options = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions();
options.AppId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FBappId"];
options.AppSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FBappSecret"];
string[] FBScopes = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FBScope"].ToString().Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach (string s in FBScopes)
{
    options.Scope.Add(s);
}

Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter.Messages.RequestToken request = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter.Messages.RequestToken();

options.Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
{
    OnAuthenticated = async context =>
    {
        //Get the access token from FB and store it in the database and
        //use FacebookC# SDK to get more information about the user
        context.Identity.AddClaim(
            new System.Security.Claims.Claim("FacebookAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
    }
};
options.SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie;
//options.SignInAsAuthenticationType = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AppBuilderSecurityExtensions.GetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(app);
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(options);
```

So far it's working fine and no such error ever appeared. Anyone know why this happens?

Have there been any security changes by facebook?

Advice me please.

Comment: Any code or other information so we even got a chance to help you? It's not a guessing game here

Comment: Perhaps you are not logged in?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, in my case, the solution was to remove android aplication in the facebook.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was the "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" property which was set to an old redirect URI I had set before.

Once I changed it to the current port, it worked correctly.

This setting is in the "Products=>Facebook Login" section.